# Contour integral principal branch

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to compute, for the principal branch, the following integral where $C$ is the circle of radius $R$ centered at $0$ and $\alpha$ is a complex number different from zero

$$\int_{C} z^{\alpha-1} \, \mathrm{d}z $$

**My attempt:**

I define the parameterization for C as follows:
$C:[0,2 \pi] \to  \mathbb{C}$ and $C(\theta)=Re^{i \theta}$.

therefore $z^{\alpha-1}= e^{(\alpha-1)\text{Log(z)}}$

So,

$$\int_{C} z^{\alpha-1}dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{(\alpha-1)\text{Log}(Re^i\theta)} \cdot iRe^{i\theta} d\theta= i R\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{(\alpha-1)\text{Log}(Re^i\theta)} \cdot e^{i\theta} d\theta$$

From here, I'm not sure how to proceed. Any advice?

Comment: Isn't $-\pi< \theta \le \pi$ for the principal branch?

Comment: Yeah, but that's for the Arg(z)

Comment: Which is $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

$z=Re^{i\theta}\\
dz = iRe^{i\theta}\ d\theta$

$\int_0^{2\pi} R^{a-1}e^{(a-1)i\theta}(iRe^{i\theta})\ d\theta\\
\int_0^{2\pi} iR^{a}e^{ai\theta}\ d\theta$

And I will let you take it home from here.